# How do I perform an action on a field for Swift UI Tests based on the contents/state of the field?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, xcode-ui-testing

I have a usernameField. On initial state, the field is empty. If I log in successfully, and log back out, it remembers my username for me.

Trying to create a test case for iOS (in swift) that will clear out the field (use the clearText button) if the field has content and then enter a desired string. If it's empty, it needs to skip the clearText button action (since it doesn't exist when the field value is nil) and go straight to entering the username.

It always skips the if statement, even when it's true. Looks for the clearText button, and fails. Works if there's a value in the field, though.

Tried lots of different approaches, but here's my best current working code. Open to any suggestions, as I have no one to really help me learn this stuff. I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental:

```
let staffusernameloginfield = app.scrollViews.otherElements.textFields["staffUsernameLoginField"]

    staffusernameloginfield.tap()

    func checkUsernameFieldContents() {
        if staffusernameloginfield == (Content:nil) {
            staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
        }

        else {
            elementsQuery.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
            staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
            }
        }

    checkUsernameFieldContents()
```

Have also tried:

```
if staffusernameloginfield == ("") {
        staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
    }

    else {
        elementsQuery.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
        staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
    }
}
```

I know that I could hack it by having it always enter a value into the field and then clear it out and enter the desired value, but in this test case, I'm not trying to test for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the value (raw attribute of the element). This type can vary so I always do it as a string:

```
if staffusernameloginfield.value as! String == "" {
    staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
}
else {
    elementsQuery.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
    staffusernameloginfield.typeText("owner")
}
```

Now it should enter 'owner' if it sees there is no value in staffusernameloginfield.

Answer (score 0):

to check if the textfield is empty:

```
app.textFields["signInEmailAddressTextFieldLabel"].value as? String == ""
```

if the textfield is empty, then that's true

I usually use an assert to check if the value is empty or not, in this example the value is equal to a variable incorrectPassword:

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.textFields["\(passwordSecureTextFieldLabel)"].value as? String, incorrectPassword)
```